# Angular 2 - Create a Tree component - Struggling with structural directives

Tags: angular, templates, angular2-directives

I try to create a tree of divs with a text (will be more complex eventualy) inside 
with a structural directive.. and it should render something like this,

```
<div>Campaign
  <div>Leaf A</div>
  <div>Leaf B</div>
</div>
<div>Customer
    <div>Parameters</div>
    <div>Segments</div>
    <div>Products</div>
</div>
```

but so far I get nested divs that are empty

here is the html template using that directive

```
<div *siteMapLeaf="'Campaign'">
     <div *siteMapLeaf="'Leaf A'"></div>
     <div *siteMapLeaf="'Leaf B'"></div>
</div>
<div *siteMapLeaf="'Customer'">
     <div *siteMapLeaf="'Parameters'"></div>
     <div *siteMapLeaf="'Segments'"></div>
     <div *siteMapLeaf="'Products'">
</div>
```

here is the directive I use:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[siteMapLeaf]' })
export class SiteMapDirective
{
    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef < any > , // content what is inside ng-Template, ie the div referenced by the directive
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
    ) {}

    @Input() set siteMapLeaf(caption)
    {
        let captionView=this.templateRef.createEmbeddedView(caption);
        this.viewContainer.insert(captionView);
    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Why not use `*ngFor` to iterate over some data structure in order to generate similar markup? Why insert a full-blown "view" vs just set the element's `innerText` (because it'll be more than just text eventually)?

Comment: innerText does not work, it works for text, but I cant insert a component template...ngFor is not suited for a tree case, so I simplified it with a simple tree like template

Comment: Fair enough. So what is that you're struggling with exactly?

Comment: well with the code above, the caption is not appearing

Comment: Does yurzui's solution work?

Comment: yes, thanks, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your templates don't have any text nodes that would render `caption`. They only consist of empty `div` element.

One way to achieve your requirentments is using `Renderer2` as follows:

```typescript
@Directive({ 
  selector: '[siteMapLeaf]' 
})
export class SiteMapDirective {
  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef <any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  @Input() set siteMapLeaf(caption) {
    let captionView = this.templateRef.createEmbeddedView({});
    const parentNode = captionView.rootNodes[0];
    this.renderer.insertBefore(
          parentNode, this.renderer.createText(caption), parentNode.firstChild);
    this.viewContainer.insert(captionView);
  }
}
```

Here's an [**Stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsc3qr?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: YES !!! too bad there is not much infos about these api, just some basic official documentation